Cross-Origin Request Blocked with status code: 200, when generating document on react with Docxtemplater
I am having trouble generating document on localhost webpage. Project is with laravel 11 backend (with breeze starter-kit) and vite-react frontend.
When trying to generate it, I get error in console:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/Template_Doc.docx. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.
My backend port is on port 8000, and web port on 5173.
I have seperate folders for backend and frontend
I have saved template document in directory /backend/public/Template_Doc.docx
In backend/ I have server.js:
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const PORT = 8000;

// Global CORS middleware
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "http://localhost:5173",
        credentials: true,
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
        allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "Accept"],
        exposedHeaders: ["Content-Disposition"],
    })
);

// Pre-flight requests
app.options("*", cors());

// Middleware for all routes to ensure CORS headers
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5173");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept"
    );
    res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
    next();
});

// Route for template file
app.get("/storage/Template_Doc.docx", (req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.join(
        __dirname,
        "public",
        "storage",
        "Template_Doc.docx"
    );
    console.log("Attempting to serve template from:", filePath);

    try {
        if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
            const stats = fs.statSync(filePath);
            console.log("File found:", {
                size: stats.size,
                permissions: stats.mode.toString(8),
            });

            // Set necessary headers
            res.header(
                "Content-Type",
                "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
            );
            res.header(
                "Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=Template_Doc.docx"
            );

            // Send file
            res.sendFile(filePath, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Error sending file:", err);
                    res.status(500).send("Error sending file");
                } else {
                    console.log("File sent successfully");
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.error("File not found at:", filePath);
            res.status(404).send("File not found");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error accessing file:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Server error");
    }
});

// Start server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);

    // Check template on startup
    const templatePath = path.join(
        __dirname,
        "public",
        "storage",
        "Template_Doc.docx"
    );
    if (fs.existsSync(templatePath)) {
        const stats = fs.statSync(templatePath);
        console.log("Template file ready:", {
            path: templatePath,
            size: stats.size,
            permissions: stats.mode.toString(8),
        });
    } else {
        console.error("Template file not found at:", templatePath);
    }
});

In backend/cors.php I have setup:
'paths' => ['register', 'login', 'logout','api/*', 'Template_Doc.docx', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:5173'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true

In directory frontend/src/components/DocumentPage.jsx, I have functions:
loadFile:
function loadFile(url, callback) {
    const fullUrl = `http://localhost:8000${url}`;
    console.log('Attempting to load file from:', fullUrl);

    fetch(fullUrl, {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        },
        mode: 'cors',
    })
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.arrayBuffer();
        })
        .then((buffer) => {
            console.log('Template loaded successfully, size:', buffer.byteLength);
            callback(null, buffer);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error loading template:', error);
            alert('Error loading template. Please check if the server is running and the file is accessible.');
            callback(error);
        });
}

Also generateDocument:
const generateDocument = async (e) =\> {
e.preventDefault();
console.log('Starting document generation...');

        try {
            // Use the direct path since we're handling it in the loadFile function
            loadFile('/Template_Doc.docx', function (error, content) {
                if (error) {
                    console.error('Error loading file:', error);
                    return;
                }
                const zip = new PizZip(content);
                const doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, { paragraphLoop: true, linebreaks: true });
                doc.render(formData);
                const out = doc.getZip().generate({
                    type: 'blob',
                    mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                });
                saveAs(out, 'output.docx');
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error in generate document:', error);
            console.error('Error details:', {
                message: error.message,
                stack: error.stack
            });
            alert('Error in document generation process. Please check the console for details.');
        }
    };

QUESTION
I cannot find any solutions to this type of error online. Could anyone perhaps offer advice?

The error message says that :  ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is missing. So you could test it with curl directly, and you'll probably see that indeed the header is not set. Maybe you can set it to "*" first to see if the header is set at all.

Doing curl returns:
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: close
<...>
The http://localhost:8000/Template_Doc.docx link works for downloading file on the browser side.

Maybe you could try setting the header first to "*" to see if that works.
If it does, then you need to find out the correct string to use which is more specific.
If it does not work, then it means that most likely the header is not present. In this case you can view the headers sent/received in the devtools. Maybe there is a proxy in between or something (nginx, apache, ...)
